# How to use my own picture to generate adversarial example using FGSM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to generate adversarial example using FGSM, and the code frame i am using is from  Google Colab code(https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/generative/adversarial_fgsm.ipynb#scrollTo=wpYrQ4OQSYWk). And the kernal information of my Jupyter Book is Python3.7. However, when I tried to use my own picture to generate the adversarial example, the compilation failed all the time. Actually, the only part that I changed is "image_path = 'cat.jpg'". Well, I searched the errors on google, but it seems like there are no similar situations like this. Therefore, could you please give a hand,thanks a lot!
**Here are my codes:**

```
  import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8, 8)
mpl.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False

pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=True,
                                                     weights='imagenet')
pretrained_model.trainable = False

# ImageNet labels
decode_predictions = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.decode_predictions

# Helper function to preprocess the image so that it can be inputted in MobileNetV2
def preprocess(image):
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, (224, 224))
  image = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input(image)
  image = image[None, ...]
  return image

# Helper function to extract labels from probability vector
def get_imagenet_label(probs):
  return decode_predictions(probs, top=1)[0][0]

image_path = 'cat.jpg'
image_raw = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
image = tf.image.decode_image(image_raw)

image = preprocess(image)
image_probs = pretrained_model.predict(image)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image[0]*0.5+0.5) # To change [-1, 1] to [0,1]
_, image_class, class_confidence = get_imagenet_label(image_probs)
plt.title('{} : {:.2f}% Confidence'.format(image_class, class_confidence*100))
plt.show()

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

def create_adversarial_pattern(input_image, input_label):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(input_image)
    prediction = pretrained_model(input_image)
    loss = loss_object(input_label, prediction)

  # Get the gradients of the loss w.r.t to the input image.
  gradient = tape.gradient(loss, input_image)
  # Get the sign of the gradients to create the perturbation
  signed_grad = tf.sign(gradient)
  return signed_grad

# Get the input label of the image.
labrador_retriever_index = 208
label = tf.one_hot(labrador_retriever_index, image_probs.shape[-1])
label = tf.reshape(label, (1, image_probs.shape[-1]))

perturbations = create_adversarial_pattern(image, label)
plt.imshow(perturbations[0]*0.5+0.5); # To change [-1, 1] to [0,1]

def display_images(image, description):
  _, label, confidence = get_imagenet_label(pretrained_model.predict(image))
  plt.figure()
  plt.imshow(image[0]*0.5+0.5)
  plt.title('{} \n {} : {:.2f}% Confidence'.format(description,
                                                   label, confidence*100))
  plt.show()

epsilons = [0, 0.02, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
descriptions = [('Epsilon = {:0.3f}'.format(eps) if eps else 'Input')
                for eps in epsilons]

for i, eps in enumerate(epsilons):
  adv_x = image + eps*perturbations
  adv_x = tf.clip_by_value(adv_x, -1, 1)
  display_images(adv_x, descriptions[i])
```

**And the erros are:**

```
>     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_FallbackException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py in read_file(filename, name)
    601         _ctx._context_handle, _ctx._thread_local_data.device_name, "ReadFile",
--> 602         name, _ctx._post_execution_callbacks, filename)
    603       return _result

_FallbackException: This function does not handle the case of the path where all inputs are not already EagerTensors.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-4edeac21c176> in <module>
     27 
     28 image_path = 'cat.jpg'
---> 29 image_raw = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
     30 image = tf.image.decode_image(image_raw)
     31 

D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py in read_file(filename, name)
    605       try:
    606         return read_file_eager_fallback(
--> 607             filename, name=name, ctx=_ctx)
    608       except _core._SymbolicException:
    609         pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.

D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_io_ops.py in read_file_eager_fallback(filename, name, ctx)
    654   _attrs = None
    655   _result = _execute.execute(b"ReadFile", 1, inputs=_inputs_flat,
--> 656                              attrs=_attrs, ctx=_ctx, name=name)
    657   _execute.record_gradient(
    658       "ReadFile", _inputs_flat, _attrs, _result, name)

D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     59     tensors = pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name,
     60                                                op_name, inputs, attrs,
---> 61                                                num_outputs)
     62   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     63     if name is not None:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 57: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with some of my images and everything is ok.

it's just about your image encode.
run again with some other images or change the image encoding.